# how to dynamically download a file using struts 2 annotations (passing variable into annotation)

Tags: variables, annotations, struts, arguments

im new to struts 2 and im asking if there's a way to pass a variable argument into struts 2 annotation.

here is what i already did but with no luck

```
public class DownloadFileAction  extends ModuleGenericClass{
    private InputStream inputStream;
   private String fileName;

   @Action(value="/downloadFile",results={
         @Result(name="success",type="stream",params = {
                 "contentType",
                 "application/octet-stream",
                 "inputName","inputStream",
                 "bufferSize","1024","contentDisposition",
                 "filename=\"${fileName}\""})
         })
   public String execute() throws Exception {
         fileName = "testing";
         inputStream = //myInputStream
         return SUCCESS;
   }

    public void setCourrierId(String courrierId) {
        this.courrierId = courrierId;
    }
   public String getfileName() {
      return fileName;
   }

   public void setfileName(String fileName) {
      this.fileName = fileName;
   }

   public InputStream getInputStream() {
       return inputStream;
   }

   public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
       this.inputStream = inputStream;
   }
}
```

i searched on the net but i found only solutions with xml Struts and that is not what i want =(

Comment: Your getter should be `getFileName`, does it work with the correct name?

Comment: shame on me, i spent hours searchingin the time where the mistake is in front of my eyes =$
thank you so much it does work

Comment: Fresh eyes often spot things immediately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filename getter method is named incorrectly, it should follow the JavaBean pattern:

```
public String getFileName() { ... }
```

OGNL's failing to call the getter; dynamic parameters work in annotations as they do in XML.