# How to download localy file with Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

I want to download xml file with my struts application.
I recup my xml in JAVA (in my action) .  When I click to my link, the download window doesn't open . 
This my code : 
ACTION :

```
@Action(value = "download", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", type = "redirectAction", params = {
                    "actionName", "testMM"}),
            @Result(name = "input", location = "testMM.jsp") })
    public String dowload() {
        setFilePath(getSession().get("filePath", String.class));
        setFileName(getSession().get("fileName", String.class));

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("c://mm.xml");



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

/**
     * @return the fileInputStream
     */
    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    }
```

MY JSP:

```
<s:url id="fileDownload" namespace="/adminMM" action="download" ></s:url>
<s:a  style="width: 300px; maring: 15px 25px;" href="%{fileDownload}"><s:text name="%{resultFileName}" /></s:a>
```

Please I need help . I can give you more information .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611088/how-to-dynamically-download-a-file-using-struts-2-annotations-passing-variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18825385/573032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When downloading a file with Struts2, you need to use the [Stream result type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300376/1654265):

   ```
   @Action(value = "download", 
       results = {
           @Result(name = "success", type = "stream", params = {
                   "contentType"        , "text/xml",
                   "inputName"          , "fileInputStream",
                   "contentDisposition" , "attachment;filename=\"foobar.xml\""
           }),
           @Result(name = "input", location = "testMM.jsp") 
       }
   )
   ```
2. Return an ERROR in case of file not found, you are just printing the stacktrace and returning SUCCESS the same;
3. Correct the typo in the `dowload` method that must be `download`.